# hide and unhide the masterView in UISplitView iOS 5.1 and iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I read many answer in stackoverflow but I am confused, How we can hide and unhide the `masterView` in `UISplitView` (iOS 5.1 and iOS 6).

On a button click on `detailViewController`, I want to show `MasterViewController` but `willShowViewController` method is not called?

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
// Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = nil;
}
```

On the the change in orientation above method called, but I wants when user click on a button in detailViewController, MasterViewController should be appear

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing following:
Call the below function on click of a button in Detail View Controller .

```
- (void)hideUnhide
{
    doHideMasterView = !doHideMasterView // a bool variable
    if(doHideMasterView)
    {
         self.MasterViewController = [SplitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
         [SplitViewController.viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        SplitViewController.controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.MasterViewController,self.DetailViewController,nil];
    }
}
```